# Host header attacks: Possible exploits

Tags: webserver, shared-hosting, header

We have an API server hosted with amazon elb. The server has only one virtual host and hence it doesn't enforce `Host` header. But if we manually add a `Host` header along with the request with a valid host name, the server returns a success.

Is there any possibilities by which this can be exploited in general? 
Is it usually recommended to use a `Host` header with every request?

Comment: Even if the server is fine without it, a host header is mandatory in HTTP - so why not just adhere to the specification and send one? (Also, are you only asking from the perspective of the client or also about risks of not verifying a host header on the server side?)

Comment: @Arminius There is no code level checks implemented for Host header. I was wondering whether any host header inclusion/injection attacks work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is not a vulnerability in itself, but enables the exploitation of other vulnerabilities.

Recently [an attack was published for Wordpress](https://exploitbox.io/vuln/WordPress-Exploit-4-7-Unauth-Password-Reset-0day-CVE-2017-8295.html) that depended on the site being available independent of the value of the Host header.

- Attacker requests a password reset with Host header set to attacker-controlled domain: `Host: attacker.com`.
- Wordpress sends a password reset token to the email address of the user, with the sender set to wordpress@attacker.com.
- If this email bounces or is replied to, the attacker receives the token on wordpress@attacker.com.

Edit: a [DNS rebinding attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) also only works if the web site ignores the host header. It works like this:

- A user visits attacker.com.
- The attacker changes the DNS entry for attacker.com to point to your amazon elb server.
- The page on attacker.com does a HTTP request using Javascript to attacker.com. This is permitted according to the same-origin policy, but since the DNS has changed it is actually a cross origin request.